# publics key between windows 2012 server and aix system

Tags: openssh

I am have problem with my keys generated in both system Windows server 2012 and Aix version 7.20
The sftp or ssh from windows to aix is working (no password require to connect) but the same sftp or ssh from Aix to Windows prompt me for password.  When i ssh_add id_rsa.pub I have this message
Permissions for 'id_rsa.pub' are too open.
It is required that your private key files are NOT accessible by others.
This private key will be ignored.
thanks

Comment: `ssh-add` doesn't work with public-keys. Nonetheless, you can do this: `chmod 0400 id_rsa.pub`. Anyways, have you got a running ssh-server on your Windows?

Comment: Is it possible to issu chmod  command on windows ? if yes how

Comment: If you tried `ssh-add id_rsa.pub` on Aix, then use `chmod 0400 id_rsa.pub` on Aix, too.

Comment: @LorinczyZsigmond The permissions on id_rsa.pub don't matter, because ssh-add isn't supposed to be used with the .pub file. Talking about how to change permissions on id_rsa.pub is just misleading.

Comment: Please note that from Windows server I am able to ssh or sftp to aix  server withour password prompt The main problem is from aix server to Windows that even with key exchange is still asking for password. There is something wrong somewhere

Comment: Hi, my problem was solved. The windows permission on the file authorized_keys was wrong. Thanks for the support